# Error when serializing dataset with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to use protobuf-net to serialize a dataset but getting the below error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: No
>   suitable Default DataSet encoding
>   found.    at
>   ProtoBuf.Serializer.ThrowNoEncoder(DataFormat
>   format, Type valueType)    at
>   ProtoBuf.Property.PropertyFactory.CreateProperty[T](Type
>   type, DataFormat&  format,
>   MemberSerializationOptions options)
>   at
>   ProtoBuf.Property.PropertyFactory.Create[T](MemberInfo
>   member)    at
>   ProtoBuf.Serializer`1.Build()

Below is the code being used

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Packet
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public DataSet Data { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


    using (var fs = new FileStream("test0.txt", FileMode.Create))
    {
       Serializer.Serialize(fs, packet);
       Console.WriteLine("Total bytes with protobuf-net = " + fs.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSet` is not *really* a data-contract, and there is no supported implementation in "v1" (the code available as pre-built dll). I have, however, done some playing in "v2" [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/10/datatable-life-in-old-beast.html) that may be of interest, including a range of metrics for comparison / decision-making.